# Send multiple outputs to file without overriding

Tags: unix

I'm trying to send the output of two commands in UNIX to a file called "log.txt"

Right now I've been trying:

```
# date ; quota -v myName > log.txt
```

The intent is to have my log.txt file look like:

```
Mon Sep 11 14:13:34 PDT 2006
Disk Quota for ....
...
...
```

Where the first line represents the date command and the rest represent the quota command.

Is there a way to send the outputs of both of these commands to the same log.txt file without overriding each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses to group your commands for the redirect of standard output.

```
(date ; quota -v myName) > log.txt
```

For example:

```
# (date; echo "hi") > foo
# cat foo
Sat Feb  9 23:09:15 PST 2013
hi
```

Louis's answer of `>>` works better if you want to have many commands in a big script.  The first command should use `>` so that it truncates any existing contents of the file.  All the other commands use `>>` to append to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You want to append, use the *>>* So something like:

```
date >> log.txt && quota -v myName >> log.txt
```